# Вместо массива с значениями функция возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, массивы, undefined-reference

Функция `returnWay` должна возвращать массив с символами, в debug я видел, что массив заполняется значениями, но когда `returnWay` возвращает этот массив, он переходит в `undefined`.

Весь код:

```
var graph = {};
            graph['start'] = {};
            graph['start']['a'] = 5;
            graph['start']['b'] = 2;
                graph['a'] = {};
                graph['a']['c'] = 8;
                graph['a']['d'] = 2;
                graph['b'] = {};
                graph['b']['a'] = 8;
                graph['b']['d'] = 7;
                    graph['c'] = {};
                    graph['c']['end'] = 3;
                    graph['c']['d'] = 6;
                    graph['d'] = {};
                    graph['d']['end'] = 1;
                        graph['end'] = {};

        var prices = {};
            prices['a'] = 5;
            prices['b'] = 2;
            prices['c'] = Infinity;
            prices['d'] = Infinity;
            prices['end'] = Infinity;

        var parents = {};
            parents['a'] = 'start';
            parents['b'] = 'start';
            parents['c'] = null;
            parents['d'] = null;
            parents['end'] = null;

        var processed = [];

        function de (graph, prices, parents, end) {
            var node = lowerPrice(prices);
            while (node !== null) {
                var price = prices[node];
                var neighbors = graph[node];
                for (i in neighbors) {
                    var newPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(neighbors[i]);
                        if (prices[i] > newPrice) {
                            prices[i] = newPrice;
                            parents[i] = node;
                        }
                }
                processed.push(node);
                node = lowerPrice(prices);
            }
            var wayEnd = [];
            returnWay(end, wayEnd);//.join('=>');
        }

        function lowerPrice(prices) {
            var lowPrice = Infinity;
            var lowNode = null;
            for (i in prices) {
                var thisPrice = prices[i];
                if ((thisPrice < lowPrice) && (processed.indexOf(i) == -1)) {
                    lowPrice = thisPrice;
                    lowNode = i;
                } 
            }
            return lowNode;
        }

        function returnWay (end, way) {
            if (parents[end] !== undefined) {
                way.push(end);
                returnWay(parents[end], way);
            }
            else {
                return way;
            }
        }

        console.log(de(graph, prices, parents, 'end'));
```

Функция `returnWay`:

```
function returnWay (end, way) {
            if (parents[end] !== undefined) {
                way.push(end);
                returnWay(parents[end], way);
            }
            else {
                return way;
            }
        }
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас  `function de` не возвращает никакое значение, как и первая ветка в `function returnWay`, я  добавил 2 `return` и что-то вернулось, что делает Ваш алгоритм я не думал...

```js
var graph = {};
            graph['start'] = {};
            graph['start']['a'] = 5;
            graph['start']['b'] = 2;
                graph['a'] = {};
                graph['a']['c'] = 8;
                graph['a']['d'] = 2;
                graph['b'] = {};
                graph['b']['a'] = 8;
                graph['b']['d'] = 7;
                    graph['c'] = {};
                    graph['c']['end'] = 3;
                    graph['c']['d'] = 6;
                    graph['d'] = {};
                    graph['d']['end'] = 1;
                        graph['end'] = {};

        var prices = {};
            prices['a'] = 5;
            prices['b'] = 2;
            prices['c'] = Infinity;
            prices['d'] = Infinity;
            prices['end'] = Infinity;

        var parents = {};
            parents['a'] = 'start';
            parents['b'] = 'start';
            parents['c'] = null;
            parents['d'] = null;
            parents['end'] = null;

        var processed = [];

        function de (graph, prices, parents, end) {
            var node = lowerPrice(prices);
            while (node !== null) {
                var price = prices[node];
                var neighbors = graph[node];
                for (i in neighbors) {
                    var newPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(neighbors[i]);
                        if (prices[i] > newPrice) {
                            prices[i] = newPrice;
                            parents[i] = node;
                        }
                }
                processed.push(node);
                node = lowerPrice(prices);
            }
            var wayEnd = [];
            //// вот тут надо вернуть значение
            return returnWay(end, wayEnd);//.join('=>');
        }

        function lowerPrice(prices) {
            var lowPrice = Infinity;
            var lowNode = null;
            for (i in prices) {
                var thisPrice = prices[i];
                if ((thisPrice < lowPrice) && (processed.indexOf(i) == -1)) {
                    lowPrice = thisPrice;
                    lowNode = i;
                } 
            }
            return lowNode;
        }

        function returnWay (end, way) {
            if (parents[end] !== undefined) {
                way.push(end);
                //// и вот тут тоже надо вернуть значение
                return returnWay(parents[end], way);
            }
            else {
                return way;
            }
        }

        console.log(de(graph, prices, parents, 'end'));
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает, но я не могу понять почему нужно возвращать значение в первой ветке returnWay, если не сложно, разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну так как Вы вызываете эту функцию рекурсивно, для поддержания цепочки return, а иначе получается что после первого захода в первую ветку из этой функции вернется `undefined`